# Failure to determine screen point of hittable tableViewCell

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing

To UI test of my app, I have to enable/disable iCloud. I do this by launching the Settings app in my test, navigate to the *Apple ID* scene, and tap there the *iCloud* cell (see image below).

[image]

In my test, I check that the iCloud cell exists and is hittable. Only then I tap the cell:

```
// when
let iCloudCell = settingsApp.tables.cells["iCloud"]
let iCloudCellFound = iCloudCell.waitForExistence(timeout: 10)
// then
XCTAssert(iCloudCellFound, "iCloud settings not found")
XCTAssert(iCloudCell.isHittable, "iCloud settings not hittable")

// when
iCloudCell.tap()
```

This works most of the time, but now and then the test stops at `iCloudCell.tap()` with the log

```
t =   113.74s         Find: Descendants matching type Table
t =   113.74s         Find: Descendants matching type Cell
t =   113.74s         Find: Elements matching predicate '"iCloud" IN identifiers'
t =   113.85s     Synthesize event
t =   113.97s         Assertion Failure: <unknown>:0: Failed to determine screen point of "iCloud" Cell: Error copying attributes -25202
```

**EDIT:**
When this error happens, only the Apple ID scene is shown. No alert, and no other view.

My question is: How can this be that the cell is hittable, but the screen point cannot be determined? And what could be a workaround?

Comment: This can sometimes happen if another view is shown over the top of the view you are trying to tap, or if the screen is dimmed for a popover or system alert. Are you 100% sure neither of those are happening during your test?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the case. Just the Apple ID scene is shown. No other view, no alert. I will edit my question to make this clear. Thanks for the pointing out this possibility.